# How to create update process for single entry form in APEX 4.1

Tags: forms, oracle-apex, updates, tabular-form

I'm new to APEX. I am sure this solution might be available, but was unable to find a proper answer anywhere.

Here is the case scenario: (Provide user a capability to update a particular report row).

Page 1 has report A in which there is a particular column say column B which has links to all its row, by clicking on one particular row user navigates to the new page (Page2).

Page 2 has single entry form in region one which has list of items (around 10) and on region 2 of the same page (page 2) it has a tabular form.

Some of the items in region 1 of page 2 are populated based on the information from page 1 report details. Some items have LOVs and some item user can add information.

The tabular form in region 2 of page 2 is generated based on line item id which can be edited by the user. The tabular form is associated to one table only.

There are two buttons on the page, cancel button takes back to the report page, whereas the save button will save the data to the database tables. The single form items will update 2 tables, whereas tabular form will update one tables.

How the process needs to be establish for updating the underlying tables through apex.

Right now Tabular form has MRU update built in process(but I am not sure can I use this process in coordination with single entry form or it is better to create a separate process which handles both updates)

Can anybody give me an idea how this can be accomplished, or a link where such process has been explained?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to manually create plsql processes to process the submitted values and apply them to your tables. You can not use the built-in row processing to do this: you can not define 2 per page. (That makes sense because you can not indicate which column maps to which table. You can only define "database column" as source for an item. This means that even if you were to have 2 processes, these columns would be attempted to process on both processes, which would lead to errors.)

Take a look at this post for some ideas on how to set the processes up: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7877933/814048

Comment: thanks, I am following the link that u provided. is there any way to check if the value of the item is updated or not and only update the underlying table/column if it is updated. I mean do APEX have some functionalities that we can use to check that. what about tabular form, is there anyway to check if the row element has been updated, and if it is updated then only update only those few columns.. and not all. and if no field is updated do not process the update...

Comment: Yes. This is the "Optimistic Locking" part of the linked post. This is rowlevel. If you need it even more granular, you could attempt to use apex_item.md5_checksum http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23903_01/doc/doc.41/e21676/apex_item.htm#CHDHHGIG , though that'll get creative :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if :P42_ORDER_STATUS in ('IP','OW') then
begin
    FOR I in 1..APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01.COUNT LOOP
        
        update sales_mst set ORDER_STATUS = 'DR'
        where id = to_number(apex_application.g_f01(i));
    end loop;
end;
end if;
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.