# ORACLE EXPRESS: build a page with multiple forms linked to one table

Tags: oracle-apex

im using oravle application express. APEX
i would like to build a page with multiple forms linked to one table (orders) , the page has 4 from  each one with different order_id number (depending on filtering),  and if the order is prepared click yes for each order and this 'YES' should be UPDATED AND SAVED to each order number in the same table with the press of one button.

i created all the form as (sql query)

and create one update process

```
(UPDATE ORDERS
SET TRAY_PREPARED =:P10_TRAY_PREPARED_1
WHERE ORDER_ID =:P10_ORDER_ID_1;

UPDATE ORDERS
SET TRAY_PREPARED =:P10_TRAY_PREPARED_2
WHERE ORDER_ID =:P10_ORDER_ID_2;


UPDATE ORDERS
SET TRAY_PREPARED =:P10_TRAY_PREPARED_3
WHERE ORDER_ID =:P10_ORDER_ID_3;

UPDATE ORDERS
SET TRAY_PREPARED =:P10_TRAY_PREPARED_4
WHERE ORDER_ID =:P10_ORDER_ID_4;
)
```

i dont know really if i can do that, but it appear hat it actually saving according to order_id number , but not all the time some time it saved the value as "null".

please guide me what is the correct way to do this.

I READ THIS ONE 
[APEX - Creating a page with multiple forms linked to multiple related tables... that all submit with one button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877396/apex-creating-a-page-with-multiple-forms-linked-to-multiple-related-tables)
BUT IT WAS FOR MULTIPLE INSERT

thanks.

---

Answer (score 0):

If your 4 forms all use the same form fields/table columns, you're better of creating a tabular form on your table.